# Evince - unable to change zoom level max. resolution

Tags: gnome, evince

At hand we have a large PDF file with geo data, thus SVG graphics. When loading the PDF in the document viewer (evince) the max. zoom level is 69.3%.

Trying to change max. zoom level ... checking with `gsettings get evince page-cache-size` throws error that schema evince doesn't exist. Checking by `gsettings list-schemas | grep vince` yields the fact that evince is registered as Evince (capital letter E) in Ubuntu.

A recursive search yields:

```
~$ gsettings list-recursively |grep Evince
org.gnome.Evince allow-links-change-zoom true
org.gnome.Evince auto-reload true
org.gnome.Evince document-directory @ms 'file:///home/...'
org.gnome.Evince override-restrictions true
org.gnome.Evince page-cache-size uint32 50
org.gnome.Evince pictures-directory @ms nothing
org.gnome.Evince show-caret-navigation-message true
org.gnome.Evince.Default continuous true
org.gnome.Evince.Default dual-page false
org.gnome.Evince.Default dual-page-odd-left false
org.gnome.Evince.Default enable-spellchecking true
org.gnome.Evince.Default fullscreen true
org.gnome.Evince.Default inverted-colors false
org.gnome.Evince.Default show-sidebar true
org.gnome.Evince.Default show-toolbar true
org.gnome.Evince.Default sidebar-page 'thumbnails'
org.gnome.Evince.Default sidebar-size 148
org.gnome.Evince.Default sizing-mode 'automatic'
org.gnome.Evince.Default window-ratio (1.0135135816534613, 0.7126568014219119)
org.gnome.Evince.Default zoom 1.0
org.gnome.shell favorite-apps ['nemo.desktop', 'io.github.cboxdoerfer.FSearch.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'vivaldi-stable.desktop', 'org.gnome.Calculator.desktop', 'xsane.desktop', 'org.gnome.Screenshot.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'libreoffice-calc.desktop', 'gnome-control-center.desktop', 'syncthing-start.desktop', 'syncthing-ui.desktop', 'org.x.Warpinator.desktop', 'org.gnome.Evince.desktop', 'threema.desktop']
```

So the page cache size is an unassigned 32 bit integer, i. e. 0x00000032 and the default zoom level is 1.0. What is the correct value to allow zoom to 400% or larger always? Which other key needs to be changed?

`System: Kernel: 5.15.0-88-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME 42.9 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, increasing the page-cache-size from 50 (default) to 500 helped here to increase zoom from 49 % to 132 % for a 1750 mm x 750 mm PDF:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Evince page-cache-size 'uint32 500'
```

Comment: Correct but you won't find the correct value to scale to 400% since it's depending on file size. I do not understand why this is blocked in the version delivered with Ubuntu hence the question. BTW 'gsettings set org.gnome.Evince page-cache-size 500' would work too - how would a "regular" user find out...

Comment: I guess what beats me is the fact that this is not left to the user to decide. Newer HW has plenty of RAM even mine (12 years old) is running on 24 GB ... why no dialog to increase the cache size?